# What's the normal rpm and sensors temperature for Macbook pro 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

I have a Macbook Pro 2019 (Core i7 16GB 16inch) and for normal usage with Google Chrome and VSCode for simple projects, it shows this temperature and fan speed

[image]

Is it normal?
Its fan are always on and I think it isn't normal.

I disabled Spotlight and Activity Monitor shows these details.

[image]

Comment: Do you have it plugged into power? If yes, then try charging it from the right side. Temps seem ok, except battery is a bit higher than what I am seeing. Fans spin always, however under such small load they should be at their baseline IMO. However, I dont own that device so maybe this is ok

Comment: yes this pictures took when it plugged into power. But it charged from right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is all normal and within specs.

If you have no particular problem with the machine, there's no need to examine temperatures and RPMs closely. The machine will do that by itself and adjust according to your environment and workload.

Comment: To add to this fine comment: macOS will shut the machine down if it senses the temps are getting high enough to cause damage to the components.